# sort single column with both questions and answers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns from a survey that were recorded in a terrible way and need an efficient way to parse them. The first column is an ID number, and the second are both questions and answers from the survey.  A dummy example would be something like this:

```
ID    Message
001   What is your first name?
001   James
002   what is your first name?
002   Sarah
```

...
And so on.

I would like to rearrange the data to have a column for each user ID as the header and the questions and ansswers down that same column. Something like this:

```
001                         002
what is your first name?    what is your first name?
James                       Sarah
```

EDIT:

Here is a partial list of questions:

1. Please provide your first name.
2. Please provide your last name.
3. Please provide your email address so we can stay in touch.
4. You can either click on the button below to confirm your email, or you may manually type one in.
5. Would you be interested in keeping up-to-date about the progress of this research project?
6. On a scale of 1 to 10 (1 = least interested, 10 = very interested), how interested are you in knowing if and when your sample was tested in our research laboratory?

Thanks

Comment: is it always sorted on id with the answer as the second line?

Comment: And is there always only two per ID?

Comment: Yes. the answer always follows the question. And each ID entry is not a fixed length since some people either didnt finish the survey or were ineligible. So some answered all 15 questions while others only got through 4. thanks

Comment: Do you have a list of *all* the questions?

Comment: You have now moved into "vba would be better suited" area.  a formula would require an array formula.  The shear number would slow down the calcs to a snail's pace.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help.

Comment: If questions were entered by someone, it is certainly a possibility that they would never match with each other for example "Please provide your first name" and "provide your first name?" Is it the case?